# How to make man replace the same buffer?

Tags: buffers, manual

Instead of open many buffers I wish to have the same buffer for all calls to the man.

Comment: somthing like `dired-find-alternate-file` but for man is desiderable

Comment: I have already `(setq-default Man-notify-method 'pushy)`

Comment: Define a command that calls `kill-buffer` and then calls `man`...

Comment: In the commentary in `man.el` there is a TODO item that says: "Allow a user option to mean that all the manpages should go in the same buffer, where they can be browsed with M-n and M-p." :)

Comment: I found that what you're asking is the default behaviour of `woman`, an Elisp replacement of man already present in Emacs. (M-x `woman`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function following @Drew's excellent suggestion:

```
(defun last-man-standing ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-matching-buffers "^\*Man .*\*" nil t)
  (call-interactively #'man))
```

A couple of notes:

1. I used `call-interactively` to preserve `man`'s fancy guessing of
   which man page you want.
2. I didn't know that `kill-matching-buffers` existed, but since Emacs
   often has exactly the function you need I went `C-h f kill-match TAB`
   and sure enough, it was there.

Comment: and then: (bind-key [remap man] 'last-man-standing)

Comment: This will not work for hyperlinks in the man buffer.