# Reuse help window

Tags: buffers, window

How to set up Emacs so that once one "help" window (e.g. describe, info, man) is displayed, all subsequent "help" buffers open in the same window?

For example, if I open a describe-function buffer and then click on the link to find the function's definition, it opens in the same window, rather than opening in a (now different) other window.

#### Edit:

One way to just about get what I want is:

```
(setq display-buffer-alist
      `((,(rx bos (or "*Apropos*" "*Help*" "*helpful" "*info*" "*Summary*") (0+ not-newline))
         (display-buffer-reuse-mode-window display-buffer-pop-up-window)
         (mode apropos-mode help-mode helpful-mode Info-mode Man-mode))))
```

My remaining questions are:

1. Is there a simpler way to do it?
2. Is there a way to ensure that the help window is selected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make man replace the same buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45174/how-to-make-man-replace-the-same-buffer)

Comment: Thanks for the link but it's not the same. I want to reuse the same window but not kill the buffer.

Comment: It is not a full answer, but I just don't have a reputation for putting this into a comment. Following variable might be also relevant `switch-to-buffer-preserve-window-point nil`. I had some troubles with buffers and windows after migrated to emacs26.

Answer (score 2):

Make `*Help*` use a *dedicated window*.

One easy way to do this is to customize option `special-display-buffer-names` to add `"*Help*"` to the list value.  Takes about 20 seconds...

---

(And yes, I don't support the idea that this option is "obsolete", personally.  It should continue to be supported forever, just like the other `special-display-*` options. That we now have a fine general tool for doing this and much more, `display-buffer-alist` is not a good reason to forego the simple, easy-to-use `special-display-*` options. Just one opinion.)

---

**`C-h v special-display-buffer-names`**:

> List of names of buffers that should be displayed specially.
>
> Displaying a buffer with `display-buffer` or `pop-to-buffer`, if
>   its name is in this list, displays the buffer in a way specified
>   by `special-display-function`.  `special-display-popup-frame`
>   (the default for `special-display-function`) usually displays
>   the buffer in a separate frame made with the parameters specified
>   by `special-display-frame-alist`.  If `special-display-function`
>   has been set to some other function, that function is called with
>   the buffer as first, and nil as second argument.
>
> Alternatively, an element of this list can be specified as
>   `(BUFFER-NAME FRAME-PARAMETERS)`, where `BUFFER-NAME` is a buffer
>   name and `FRAME-PARAMETERS` an alist of `(PARAMETER . VALUE)` pairs.
>   `special-display-popup-frame` will interpret such pairs as frame
>   parameters when it creates a special frame, overriding the
>   corresponding values from `special-display-frame-alist`.
>
> As a special case, if `FRAME-PARAMETERS` contains `(same-window . t)`
>   `special-display-popup-frame` displays that buffer in the
>   selected window.  If `FRAME-PARAMETERS` contains `(same-frame . t)`,
>   it displays that buffer in a window on the selected frame.
>
> If `special-display-function` specifies some other function than
>   `special-display-popup-frame`, that function is called with the
>   buffer named `BUFFER-NAME` as first, and `FRAME-PARAMETERS` as second
>   argument.
>
> Finally, an element of this list can be also specified as
>   `(BUFFER-NAME FUNCTION OTHER-ARGS)`.  In that case,
>   `special-display-popup-frame` will call `FUNCTION` with the buffer
>   named `BUFFER-NAME` as first argument, and `OTHER-ARGS` as the
>   second.
>
> Any alternative function specified here is responsible for
>   setting up the quit-restore parameter of the window used.
>
> If this variable appears "not to work", because you added a
>   name to it but the corresponding buffer is displayed in the
>   selected window, look at the values of `same-window-buffer-names`
>   and `same-window-regexps`.  Those variables take precedence over
>   this one.
>
> See also **`special-display-regexps`**.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: Thanks for this. I fear I'm being dense but I don't get how this solves the problem. If I add `"*Help*"` to `special-display-buffer-names`, nothing seems to change. First help buffer pops to a new window, subsequent help buffer pops to a different window. Are you suggesting writing a custom `special-display-function` which takes care of the logic of identifying help buffers, or is there some more straightforward way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand. Try starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file). Then `M-x customize-option special-display-buffer-names`. Then click `INS` and insert the text `*Help*` (no `"` chars). Then set that value for the current session (or save it for future settings, if you want). You should then get only one `*Help*` window/buffer, which gets reused.

Comment: I am not getting the same result. When I follow your steps, I get help buffers in a separate frame, as I would expect since the default value of `special-display-function` is `special-display-popup-frame`. Is there some built in function that I should assign it to that would create or reuse a window in the same frame?

Comment: If you already have buffer `*Help*` displayed in a given frame the Emacs uses its window. If you do not then it displays `*Help*` in a separate frame. `emacs -Q` `C-h v special-display-buffer-names` splits the initial window, showing `*Help*` in the second window. Then setting (e.g. customizing) the variable makes Emacs reuse that `*Help*` window, instead of showing it in a separate frame. It behaves exactly like the doc says it does.